# Android: What permission/s is need to download a file to downloads directory

Tags: android, permissions

In my app, I am just trying to mkdir like this `/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_app` and download a PDF file to that directory.

While I have these in the **Manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

Lately I noticed the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is deprecated and has no impact if the app is targetting `API >=29`

But what should I replace it with and should I still keep the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for older APIs? And is these any difference in the runtime permissions behavior?

***Because strangely when I am checking on emulators and some of the devices with `API >= 30`, I removed the runtime permission, while keeping the Manifest as it is - Everything works fine, i.e download is successful. On `API <= 29` I still have to show the runtime permission popup***

Comment: On Android 11 and higher, you do not need a permission to write to `Downloads`. The cost is that you cannot *read* from `Downloads` except for files that you created. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html) for more.

Comment: Your app does not need any permission to let the DownloadManage create that subdirectory of Downloads nor any permission to let the DownloadManager create a file there.